# How do I add data from multiple JSON feeds to a Google Sheet?

Tags: json, google-sheets, lookup

How do I add data from multiple JSON feeds to a Google Sheet? The feeds need to use a lookup function to add the data from the second and third feed to the same row as the first feed. I'm using Apify Crawlers to scrub the pages and update the sheet every 5 minutes, but I need to merge data from multiple feeds.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use custom fx:**

```
=IMPORTJSON("url-here", "xpath-here")
```

---

```
function IMPORTJSON(url,xpath){

  try{
    // /rates/EUR
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);

    var patharray = xpath.split("/");
    //Logger.log(patharray);

    for(var i=0;i<patharray.length;i++){
      json = json[patharray[i]];
    }

    //Logger.log(typeof(json));

    if(typeof(json) === "undefined"){
      return "Node Not Available";
    } else if(typeof(json) === "object"){
      var tempArr = [];

      for(var obj in json){
        tempArr.push([obj,json[obj]]);
      }
      return tempArr;
    } else if(typeof(json) !== "object") {
      return json;
    }
  }
  catch(err){
      return "Error getting data";  
  }

}
```

- **https://youtu.be/EXKhVQU37WM**
- **https://youtu.be/k0su6345KDI**